# Edit web.xml from command line on Linux

Tags: xml

I'm attempting to update my tomcats web.xml file from the command line using XmlStarlet. I need to add the following to the `web-app` element:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>mobileEnabled</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I've acheived this using a number of temporary files and XmlStarlet commands:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -s "/x:web-app" -t elem -n "context-param" -v "$$" web.xml > tmp
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -s "/x:web-app/x:context-param[text()='$$']" -t attr -n "tempAttr" -v "$$" tmp > tmp1
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -u "/x:web-app/x:context-param[@tempAttr]" -v "" tmp1 > tmp
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -s "/x:web-app/x:context-param[@tempAttr]" -t elem -n "param-name" -v "TEST_$$" \
            -s "/x:web-app/x:context-param[@tempAttr]" -t elem -n "param-value" -v "VALUE_$$"  tmp > tmp1
sed 's/ tempAttr=\"[0-9]*\"//g' tmp1 > tmp
```

What I'd ideally want is to be able to do this within 1 xmlstarlet command so I do not have to create temporary files; my attempt so far isn't working.

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -s "/x:web-app" -t elem -n "context-param" -v "$$" \
    -s "/x:web-app/x:context-param[text()='$$']" -t attr -n "tempAttr" -v "$$" \
    -u "/x:web-app/x:context-param[@tempAttr]" -v "" \
    -s "/x:web-app/x:context-param[@tempAttr]" -t elem -n "param-name" -v "TEST_$$" \
    -s "/x:web-app/x:context-param[@tempAttr]" -t elem -n "param-value" -v "VALUE_$$" web.xml > tmp
```

This doesn't add the `param-name` and `param-value` sub elements to `context-param`. A cutdown version of my web.xml is available here: http://pastebin.com/YgdGk6X9

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with my second xmlstarlet command?